# Is the center of F(G)P non-trivial?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let G be a finite soluble group with a trivial center. If $J=\pi^{-1}\left(F\left(\dfrac{G}{F(G)}\right)\right)$ where $\pi$ is the canonical homomorphism is the canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $\dfrac{G}{F(G)}$ and $P$ is a $p$-Sylow the $J$ such that $p$ divides the order of $F(G)$, then $F(G)P$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with non-trivial center? $F(G)$ is the Fitting subgroup.

I have been able to show that F(G)P is a normal subgroup of G, but I am not able to show that the center of F(G)P is not trivial.

$\bullet$ $F(G)P\triangleleft G$:

I am not sure if it is correct, but I think that $\dfrac{J}{F(G)}=F\left(\dfrac{G}{F(G)}\right)$. Moreover $\dfrac{PF(G)}{F(G)}\ char\ F\left(\dfrac{G}{F(G)}\right)$ ( because $\dfrac{PF(G)}{F(G)}$ is a $p$-Sylow of $\dfrac{J}{F(G)}$ and since $\dfrac{J}{F(G)}$ is nilpotent, then $\dfrac{PF(G)}{F(G)}$ it's unique $p$-Sylow of $\dfrac{J}{F(G)}$). Now,
$$
\dfrac{J}{F(G)}=F\left(\dfrac{G}{F(G)}\right) \triangleleft \dfrac{G}{F(G)}
$$
thus
$$
\dfrac{PF(G)}{F(G)}\ char\ F\left(\dfrac{G}{F(G)}\right)\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ F\left(\dfrac{G}{F(G)}\right) \triangleleft \dfrac{G}{F(G)}.
$$
Hence
$$
\dfrac{PF(G)}{F(G)} \triangleleft \dfrac{G}{F(G)}.
$$

Comment: I have been able to show that F(G)P is a normal subgroup of G, but I am not able to show that the center of F(G)P is not trivial.

Comment: Since $p$ divides $|F(G)|$, it also divides $|Z(F(G))|$, so $P \cap Z(F(G))$ is nontrivial and normal in $P$, and hence $Z(F(G)) \cap Z(P)$ is nontrivial.

Comment: I forgot to mention that P is a p-Sylow of J. Does that change anything?

Comment: I urge you to **edit your question** to show the work you've done reaching the conclusion that $F(G)P$ is normal in $G$.  That will show us where you're stuck and it will help us understand what tools are available for your use.

Comment: I edited my post. I added the normality part, but I don't know if what I did is correct. I'm a master's student and I'm having trouble understanding an article, if I can help, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(G)$ is nilpotent, so it is a direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups. We know that $p$ divides $|F(G)|$, so its Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$ is nontrivial. So we can write $F(G) = Q \times R$, where $R$ is the direct product of all other Sylow subgroups of $F(G)$.

Now $p$-groups have nontrivial centres, so $Z(Q) \ne 1$. Also $Z(Q)$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $F(G)P$ and $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(F(G)P)$, so $Z(Q) \le P$.

There is result that says that a normal subgroup of a nontrivial $p$-group intersects its centre nontrivially, so $Z(Q) \cap Z(P) \ne 1$, and also $Z(Q) \cap Z(P) \le Z(F(G)P)$, and we have proved that $F(G)P$ has nontrivial centre.

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Comment: If you follow the argument and agree that the proof is correct  then please accept the answer - you could also consider upvoting it!